# Map Array into Dictionary based upon NSDate

Tags: ios, arrays, swift2

Hoping to figure out a cleaner more Swifty way to convert an array of objects, into a `dictionay` based upon the date property of that object. 
Only concerned with the date, ie 31 Dec 2015 - no time comparison.

So, if manyThings has 5 things that all have the date 31 Dec 2015, the dict. would have one item date and associated with that data would the the array of 5 things.

For example

```
   struct Thing {
        var name:String
        var date:NSDate
    }

    let manyThings = [Thing]()
```

At present I have it working, using a `String` as the dict. key. But surely there is nice swift way to do this.

```
func dateGroup(things:[Thing]) -> [String:[Thing]] {

    var sameDays = [String:[Thing]]()

    // sort into Dates, using local date string as filter
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone()

    for aThing in things {

        let localDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(aThing.date)

        if var thingsForDay = sameDays[localDate] {
            thingsForDay.append(aThing)
            sameDays[localDate] = thingsForDay
        }
        else {
            var empty = [Thing]()
            empty.append(aThing)
            sameDays[localDate] = empty
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also used `reduce`, in addition, I use the `??` operator to clean up the if condition.

```
func dateGroup(things:[Thing]) -> [String:[Thing]] {
    // sort into Dates, using local date string as filter
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone()

    return things.reduce([:]) {
        (var sameDays, aThing) in

        let date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(aThing.date)

        sameDays[date] = (sameDays[date] ?? []) + [aThing]

        return sameDays
    }
}
```

---

For iOS 7 and below

```
func dateByRemovingTimeFromDate(date: NSDate) -> NSDate {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components([.Year, .Month, .Day], fromDate: date)

    return calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!
}

func dateGroup(things:[Thing]) -> [NSDate:[Thing]] {

    return things.reduce([:]) {
        (var sameDays, aThing) in

        let date = dateByRemovingTimeFromDate(aThing.date)

        sameDays[date] = (sameDays[date] ?? []) + [aThing]

        return sameDays
    }
}
```

---

For iOS 8 and above `dateByRemovingTimeFromDate` can be simplified

```
func dateByRemovingTimeFromDate(date: NSDate) -> NSDate {
    return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateBySettingHour(0, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: date, options: [])!
}
```

Comment: Thanks that if condition was my major frustration. Do you know a way to compare that data without the need to converting to a String ?

Comment: @DogCoffee is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `reduce` function on your array to translate it into a `Dictionary`.  This is arguably more of a functional approach, which might qualify it as a nice `Swift` way.

```
func dateGroup(things:[Thing]) -> [String:[Thing]] {
    // sort into Dates, using local date string as filter
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone()

    return things.reduce([:]) { (reduction, aThing) -> [String:[Thing]] in
        let localDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(aThing.date)

        var result = reduction
        if var thingsForDay = result[localDate] {
            thingsForDay.append(aThing)
            result[localDate] = thingsForDay
        }
        else {
            result[localDate] = [aThing]
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

Just for reference.  There are a few methods on most collections in `Swift` that I consider to be in this camp.  There's `filter()`, `map()`, and `reduce()`.  The use of `filter()` is fairly obvious, it gives you a subset of a collection based on some closure that returns a `Bool`.  The `map()` function is used to translate from a collection to another collection where each element is converted into some other element.  The `reduce()` function is used to translate some collection into some result (in this case, that result is a `Dictionary` of sub-`Arrays` of the original collection).